# Get a table from getElementByTagName function

Tags: php, domdocument, getelementsbytagname

I've to extract a table from a web page and I've to copy this table into a PDF document.
For extract images I written the following code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://www.pecso.it/prodotto/741drinkflex-piatto-nondiv/");
$images_links = [];
$i=0;
$divTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
if (!is_null($divTags)) {
    foreach ($divTags as $div_tag) {
        if ($div_tag->hasAttribute('class') &&
            $div_tag->getAttribute('class') == 'certificazioni') {
            if ($div_tag->hasChildNodes()) {
                foreach($div_tag->childNodes as $c) {
                    if ($c->nodeName == 'a') {
                        if ($c->hasChildNodes()) {
                            foreach($c->childNodes as $cc){
                                if ($cc->nodeName == 'img') {
                                    if ($cc->hasAttribute('src')) {
                                        $src_value = $cc->getAttribute('src');
                                        $images_links[$i] = $src_value;
                                        $i++;
                                    } 
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I created some img tag using like src attribute the values saved in `$images_links`. The code is the following:

```
foreach ($images_links as $image_link) {
?>
<img src="<?php echo $image_link ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

But, for the table, I don't try to do this because it should be too long and complicated because I've to save every attributes, every value, etc.. 
Can I manipulate `$tableTags` object to create an exact copy (tags, attributes, content..) of this table on my PDF document? Can you hel me please?

Comment: Did you tried something show us codes??

Comment: I edited my post with added code